# Merging bitshifts

Tags: c++

I'm trying to exact a 3 bit value from a byte for example:

```
unsigned char r = ((253 << 5) >> 5);
```

Result value should be `5` but why does it returns 253?

Comment: Why not just use a bitmask to strip out the 3 LSB - 00000111b in your case?

Comment: It would be 5 if you shifted away the left bits but you can mask it.

Answer (score 8):

Two possibilities:

- Your expression is evaluated as an integer and cast as a sngle-byte value in the end.
- your compiler optimizes away the shift operations.

Note that your result should be 5, not 3. What you want is:

```
const unsigned char c = 253 & 0x07 ; // (00000111)
```

Your bit mask is:

```
253 | 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 | F D
  7 | 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 | 0 7
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  5 | 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 | 0 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Your expression is evaluated using ints. Change it to:

```
unsigned char r = ((unsigned char)(253 << 5) >> 5);
```

and you should get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Because of integer promotion. There is nothing in the expression `253 << 5` that limits it to work in a byte only; the type of the literal `253` is `int`.

You need to add casts, or (better, in my opinion) extract using a mask. To get the lowest-three bits from an integer, simply use:

```
const unsigned char r = 253 & ~((1 << 3) - 1);
```

This works because 1 << 3 is 8<sub>10</sub>, which in binary is 00001000<sub>2</sub>. We subtract one, to get 7<sub>10</sub> or 00000111<sub>2</sub>. We invert this, to get a mask that includes everything but the three right-most bits, i.e. 11111000<sub>2</sub>. This is then bitwise-anded with the value to do the extraction.

Above, I show the binary values using 8 bits only, extend on the left with zeroes up to your platform's `int` size since the above is done using `int` precision.